# React / Enzyme: Invariant Violation error when running Jest / Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am having some trouble with my test cases written in Jest / Enzyme. I have a React / Redux component and am trying to write a basic test but get the following error:

`Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was 'undefined'.`

This is my code:

**dashboardComponent.js**

```
import '../stylesheets/dashboardComponent.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as dashboardActions from '../actions/dashboardActions';

class DashboardComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getDashboardContent();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      < SOME JSX HERE >
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dashboardContent: state.dashboard.get('dashboardContent')
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(dashboardActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardComponent);
```

**dashboardComponent.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { DashboardComponent as Dashboard } from '../../components/dashboardComponent';

const wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard />);

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  it('renders the Dashboard component', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I am not sure why `<Dashboard />` would be undefined here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're currently exporting your wrapped component as the default export, but to use the unwrapped component in your tests you also need to export your it as a named export, i.e.

```
export class DashboardComponent extends Component { ... }

export default connect(...)(DashboardComponent)
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: This error can also be cause if you don't pass the required props for the component to render.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I never thought of this. Great Work!

Answer (score 0):

> Error: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `object`.

- solved similar error by changing export line, from

> export const TestComponent = () => { ...

to

> export **default** TestComponent = () => { ...